# Why are Enumeration Value annotations missing for Zero based indexes in my WSDL

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

My WFC project WSDL is missing EnumerationValue annotations for Zero based indexes.  It's causing problems for other systems during transformations if say JSON passes in 0 or 1 for payment method.

I've defined the enumerations of my .net class like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "PaymentMethod")]
public enum PaymentMethod
{
    [EnumMember]
    Mastercard = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    Visa = 1
}

[DataContract(Name = "RequestType")]
public enum RequestType
{
    [EnumMember]
    New = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Reload = 2
}
```

However the generated WSDL looks like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="PaymentMethod">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Mastercard"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Visa"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="PaymentMethod" nillable="true" type="tns:PaymentMethod"/>
<xs:simpleType name="RequestType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="New">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <EnumerationValue>1</EnumerationValue>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
        <xs:enumeration value="Reload">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <EnumerationValue>2</EnumerationValue>
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="RequestType" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestType"/>
```

Comment: What happens if you strip away the DataContact attributes from your enumeration? It is usually what I do to get a nicer WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. it didn't affect the WSDL at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be included in the data contract, you must apply the EnumMemberAttribute attribute. In the .NET Framework, you can always apply the special value 0 (zero) to an enumeration, which is also the default value for any enumeration. **However, even this special zero value cannot be serialized unless it is marked with the EnumMemberAttribute attribute.**

There are two exceptions to this:

- [Flag enumerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Enumeration data members with the **EmitDefaultValue property set to false** (in which case, the enumeration with the value zero is omitted from the serialized data).

  ```
  [DataContract(Name = "PaymentMethod")]
  [Flags] // <---- Try this
  public enum PaymentMethod
  {   
     [EnumMember]
     Mastercard = 0,
     [EnumMember]
     Visa = 1
  }

  [DataContract(Name = "RequestType")]
  public enum RequestType
  {
    [EnumMember]
    New = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Reload = 2
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  When I adjust the attribute to:
`[DataContract(Name = "PaymentMethod")]
    public enum PaymentMethod
    {
        [EnumMemberAttribute(Value = "0")]
        Mastercard = 0,
        [EnumMemberAttribute(Value = "1")]
        Visa = 1
    }`
It Simply changes the WSDL to this:
`<xs:simpleType name="PaymentMethod">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="0"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>`

Comment: How about adding flags?

Comment: Adding flags solved it!
Thanks for adding the code to your answer.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help you! :)